# Safari doesnt display nvd3 chart

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, safari, nvd3.js

I have the following error in Safari:

```
TypeError: 'NaN' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 'n in t')
```

This is snippet of the code that seems to be a reason for that (from safati development tools):

```
 function nn(e) {
   return function(t, n) {
     return t += e, [t > Fa ? t-2 * Fa: - Fa > t ? t + 2 * Fa: t, n]
   }
 }
```

Src: nvd3.min.js.

Charts are working correctly in any other browser (even IE). Charts type that we are using PIE, LINE BAR, BULLET.

UPDATE

I used now development version of nvd3 from here: https://raw.github.com/novus/nvd3/master/nv.d3.min.js.

I launch my meteor project in Safari and got unhandled (the same) exception. 
d3.v3.js, line 4748 ().

```
function d3_interpolateObject(a, b) {
var i = {}, c = {}, k;
for (k in a) {
  if (k in b) {
    i[k] = d3_interpolateByName(k)(a[k], b[k]);
  } else {
    c[k] = a[k];
  }
}
for (k in b) {
  if (!(k in a)) {
    c[k] = b[k];
  }
}
return function(t) {
  for (k in i) c[k] = i[k](t);
  return c;
};
```

}

I found also a snippet of my code that invokes that 'buggy' part of d3:

```
try {
   d3.select('#chart3 svg')
     .datum(data)
     .transition().duration(1000)
     .call(chart);
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

This is a 'bullet' chart. The same issue i have with line bar chart.
The data looks as the following:

```
        var data = {
            "title": "test",
            "subtitle": "test",
            "ranges": [1, 2, 3],
            "measures": [x],
            "markers": [x],
            "rangeLabels": ['test', 'test', 'test'],
            "measureLabels": ['test'],
            "markerLabels": ['test']
        };
```

where x is a float number.

Comment: I do not see the `n in t` expression here. Neither can I find this expression in nvd3.min.js I suspect that this is something that the code prettifier you are using translates the minified code to. Can you please use the un-minified version of nvd3? Otherwise, this sounds like a bug in nvd3.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of NVD3. [NVD3 runs best on WebKit based browsers](https://github.com/novus/nvd3#supported-browsers).`Google Chrome: latest version (preferred)`, `Opera 15+ (preferred)`, `Safari: latest version`, `Firefox: latest version` , and 'Internet Explorer: 9 and 10'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in internal d3 data parsing with safari specific.

So I resolved the problem with changing chart type to simple bars.